# Button that increments a counter

Tags: arduino-uno

```
#include <Adafruit_RGBLCDShield.h>
#include <utility/Adafruit_MCP23017.h>
Adafruit_RGBLCDShield lcd = Adafruit_RGBLCDShield();

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);

}

void loop() {
  uint8_t buttons = lcd.readButtons();
  int a;  
  if (buttons) {

    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);

    if (buttons & BUTTON_UP) {
      a+= 1;
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print(a);
    }
  }
```

I am trying to make a counter that increments everytime the button UP is pressed. Currently, all it is doing is printing 1 everytime the button is pressed. Any help would be nice! Thanks!

Comment: Try "static int a = 0;"

Comment: It has to do with `int a;`. There's no "starting point" of what `a` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code, simplified, is:

```
void loop()
    int a;
    a += 1;
}
```

The problem here is that, by putting the declaration of your counter variable within the `loop()` function, you've made it local to that function. Every time `loop()` is called, a new variable `a` is created, initialized to zero, and then incremented.

You want to move the declaration outside of `loop()`, creating a global variable that will remain in existence and maintain its value after `loop()` exits, so that the value is still there when `loop()` is called again:

```
int a = 0;
void loop() {
    a += 1;
}
```

(This could also be done with a static variable, but that's probably beyond the scope of this question.)